# Adding variables to data-config of Solr data import

Tags: xml, xslt, solr

I tried to add a variable to `data-config.xml` for Solr data import but I have got the following error message when I tried to perform the data import:

> **Data Config problem: The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:variable" is
>   not bound.**

The following data-config.xml I tried :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:variable name="fileName" select="6781" />
<dataConfig>
<dataSource name="a" driver="net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver" type="JdbcDataSource" url="jdbc:ucanaccess://E:/feqh/Wak1/Wak1/main.mdb;memory=false"/>

<dataSource name="a1" driver="net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver" type="JdbcDataSource" url="jdbc:ucanaccess://E:/feqh/Wak1/Wak1/${fileName}.mdb"/>

<document>
    <entity name="Book" dataSource="a" query="select bkid AS id, bkid AS BookID,bk AS BookTitle, betaka AS BookInfo, cat as cat from 0bok WHERE bkid = ${fileName}">
```

I dynamically, using PHP script, change the config file and I want a single place i.e. variable to change its value and then propagate it to all places needing it. Is it possible? Are there any mistakes in the xslt code I use?

Comment: Technically, the XML that you have there is not an XSLT sheet since this would require the tag `<xsl:stylesheet>` and the declaration of the namespace `xsl`. So what you are trying to do is to insert a fragment of an XSLT sheet into a XML configuration file that does not have the namespace declared. This is very unlikely to work. I assume that if there are any mechanism handling variables in the configuration setup they will probably not use the XSLT namespace and tags.

Comment: An option that you could try: generate the whole configuration file from a input XML file using XSLT. That way you could propagate any variables into may places (possibly many configuration files). For this however, you need: a) the definition of the input file, b) an XSLT sheet and c) a XSLT processor (probably provided by PHP).

Comment: Could you use the second approach described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23364440/partial-schema-sharing-is-it-possible/23382975#23382975 moving your variable to a property file?

Comment: @cheffe Do you mean that instead of editing the `data-config.xml` itself, I should edit `core.properties` then just propagate the variable inside the `data-config.xml`?

Comment: Exactly this way my thought. You could use your script to change the properties file. Of course you would need to reload the config after the change, but you would need to do that anyway.

Comment: @cheffe DIH config is reloaded on every request anyway.

Comment: I tried this solution but it gives unexpected results. I think, since, I sue PHP script to interact with the xml of data-config.xml, it will be easier to load a template file for the data-config.xml let we say data-config.txt and then replace all occurance of templated value with the values I need then save it as data-config.xml